scipy.optimize.curve_fit stopped working after running several iterations
----- updates 2:
when i was stuck here, I also revised my codes to using optuna -- and looks like optuna works better than curve_fit.
----- updates 1:
the issue was due to "maxfev", and it was solved after I increased the value of "maxfev". for some reason that I don't know, on my machine, scipy did not raise any exception to me -- i'll reinstall scipy.
Thank you all who helped me diagonose this problem.
----- original post:
I wanted to use scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit the data, and I have more than 10000 data sets to fit, so I used a for loop to run curve_fit for 10000 times. However, curve_fit only worked successfully for the first 49 iterations, and after that curve_fit stopped working--to be more specific, the curve_fit function did not return anything, and it did not raise any exceptions or warnings either. What could be the reason and how to fix it?
I've included my code below. When I run it, it prints i up to 48, and then exits the for loop. There are no errors, warnings, return values, or anything.
def irt(x, alpha, beta):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(0 - alpha * (x - beta)))

for i in range(10000):
    """ I did something here to process the data, and these lines are skipped for simplicity """
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(irt, xdata[i], ydata[i], p0=[1.0, 0.5], full_output=False)
    print(i)


Please see the following example, I run the following lines in the console after running curve_fit for 49 iterations. "ress" is the return value, but nothing was returnned. (no matter what values are inputed, i got nothing from the curve_fit function)
theta = np.array([0.80748663, 0.86585366, 0.8245614 , 0.79310345, 0.63513514, 0.82926829, 0.73684211, 0.91358025, 0.79310345, 0.81818182])
correct = np.array([0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.])
ress = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(irt, theta, correct, p0=[1.0, 0.8181818181818182])
ress

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ress' is not defined.

If i just run the curve_fit function in the console, it didn't return anything:

This is difficult to investigate as such. Does it also happen if you feed the same data set 50 or more times? If so, can you generate a reproducible example? Also, did you try different versions of scipy/python?

Also, note that your function is linear, if you transform z = ln(1/y - 1) and gamma = alpha * beta. Then z = -alpha * x + gamma. As such, you can solve it as a linear least squares problem, robust and without iterations.

@Dr.V It is a bit hard for me to generate some data that you can reproduce it. But your 2nd comment, that transform the problem to a linear least square sound a good fix to my problem. I'll do that. thank you!

you won't necessarily get the same results if you linearise the equation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115441/why-can-we-linearize-the-exponential-regression

@Nin17 sure of course, they are different, but at least it can be a dirty fix for me, so i don't have to be stuck here. or i would also like to write my own optimizer (haven't done so for years after i graduated).

The problem you are presenting is very strange but it is impossible to investigate it because the lack of [mcve].

"There are no errors, warnings, return values, or anything." What do you mean by "no return value?" If a function like this returns None, then the next part which unpacks the return value into the variables popt, pcov would have an error. Is it returning (None, None) or something? Is it exiting the Python process without a message?

@NickODell that's something I cannot understand either. Because popt, pcov are in the for loop, both of them are the values of the previous loop, and their values are not updated.

@jlandercy I am working on a big data matrix of size 70K * 45K (both X and Y matrix are of this large size). I need to do a curve_fit using each row of the matrix. When I generated small sub-matrix of the raw data, and this problem never occurred. "curve_fit" worked very well. But when i started to run the same script on the raw data, it stopped after 49 iterations. I just don't know how to present a reproducible example.

@YunWei "I just don't know how to present a reproducible example." Steps 1) Can you use np.savetxt() to save copies of all relevant arrays? 2) Can you write a program which loads these arrays from a file with np.loadtxt() and shows the same problem? 3) Are the full arrays needed to show the problem, or can you save just the first 100 rows, and show that it only loops over the first 49? 4) You now have a reproducible example once you have the array text files plus the program that loads them.

@NickODell I just pasted a screenshot. Does it work? thanks

@YunWei "I just don't know how to present a reproducible example." Have you read the link?

"Does it work?" I get an error, though not the same one. "RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 600." I wonder if it's just not displaying the error for you. I don't know why it would not display the error.

What version of scipy are you using?

@jlandercy yes, i read it. I was now working on the reproducible example, when I saw Nick's comment, and he's right that "maxfev" is the issue. On my machine, it just did not raise the exception to me. Thank you so much.

@NickODell Oh great thank you so much. It is the issue. I increased the "maxfev" value and now it works! So for some reason (that i dont know), on my machine "curve_fit" doesn't raise any exception to me, so I never see this error message.

@Yun Wel and @Nin17: I agree, the result is not the same. I would still go for the linear variant and rather weight the equations in a meaningful way. E.g., if you weight each equation of the linear system with 1 / (y - y^2)^2, the result should be the same (I may have made a mistake). But maybe another weighting is more meaningful for the underlying data.

How does correct == 0 == 1/(1 + exp(...)) make any sense? That suggests that alpha or beta are infinite.

@Reinderien,  I tried the linear transformation, and it also worked.
because a small number such as 1e-16 will be transformed to 36, so i just let it be 36 instead of infinity. It's how i solved the infinity problems, and not sure if you have a better solution.
